# Checking filenames and folders for spelling mistakes

Tags: 16.04, directory, filename, spell-checking

Is there is a way to check the spelling of multiple filenames and folder names with one app or command?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command to do this would be

```
ls | aspell list
```

This will grab the names of all folders and files in the current directory, run them through a spell checker, and then list the names that have errors.

I'm going to explain this command by each part.

### `ls` explanation

This will output the contents of the current directory which we then pass to our next command, `aspell list`.

#### `aspell list` explanation

This part of the command reads the output of our last command (`ls`) and lists all of the misspelled words.

### Adding this as a custom command

You can even add this one-liner as a command if you plan on using it a lot by doing this:

First, make a new blank file (name it whatever you like, but keep in mind that this will be the command that you type when you want to use it, so **name it something other than an existing command**) and put the command that we did earlier in there.

```
echo "ls | aspell list" > YOUR_FILENAME_HERE
```

Then, give that file run permissions

```
chmod +x YOUR_FILENAME_HERE
```

Finally, move the script to `/usr/local/bin`

```
mv YOUR_FILENAME_HERE /usr/local/bin
```

Now whenever you type `YOUR_FILENAME_HERE` (remember that this is replaced with whatever you named the file in the beginning) in console, it will execute the commands that I mentioned earlier.